# SparkSession And SparkContext

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have one machine with spark 3 installed. I am opening two bash terminals of same machine and opening pyspark shell inside it. We will get two different spark sessions as in pyspark shell we got one spark session already created. So two different spark sessions.

If i open one pyspark shell in one tab. In another tab i submit a job using spark-submit with getOrCreate and print returned spark session object. I can see both spark sessions are different which should be.

The question spark 3 provides multiple spark sessoion to be connect to same spark context. So as spark context is part of spark session (spark.sparkContext) then how under the hood it is acheived. Also both the spark session lies on different process JVMs. So how it is able to connect the spark context present in another JVM.

Is spark context per application bases or per machine bases. Means Lets say i have 5 application of spark. I run first. It will create a spark context. Then if i run second to fifth will this have saprate spark context or it will share the same created by one (Basically when one spark script will run it will create one spark context and will store it on some cache location in machine and when other application will run using different spark session will look at this cached location and will use if it is available.)

What is the use case or benifits over other that it offers multiple sparksessions to use same spark context.

Will the spark context will container application specific data or its just a object which is used to access spark core api. It stores or maintains nothing application specific.